How can I use the FastAPI Depends chain asynchronously?
As the title suggests, I want to use FastAPI's Depends to implement role-based authentication control for specific routes.
I have two files. If I write the authentication logic as shown below:
auth.py file
 class Authenticator:   
    async def get_sub(self, token: Annotated[str, Depends(oauth2_scheme)]) -> str:
        ** asynchronous operation **
        return sub

    async def get_user(self, sub: Annotated[User, Depends(get_sub)]) -> UserInDB:
        sub = await self.get_sub(token)
        user = await self.user_db.get_user_by_id(id=id)
        if not user:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, detail="Not register yet")
        return user
authenticator = Authenticator()

router.py file
router = APIRouter(prefix="/user", dependencies=[Depends(authenticator.get_user)])



@router.get("/")
async def protected_route(request: Request):
    pass

If I write the get_user function in the first file with sub: Annotated[User, Depends(get_sub)], a "self" query parameter appears in the route when I run it, which seems odd. How can I make this asynchronous Depends chain work properly without the "self" issue?
know how asynchronous Depends chain work

Do you really need to group these dependencies in the class? Why don't you just use 2 functions instead?

If you don't need to access self in the get_sub method, you can make it static: use @staticmethod decorator and remove self from the signature

If you don't need to use self in get_sub, you can make get_sub static method:
class Authenticator:
    @staticmethod
    async def get_sub(token: Annotated[str, Depends(oauth2_scheme)]) -> str:
        ** asynchronous operation **
        return sub

    async def get_user(self, sub: Annotated[User, Depends(get_sub)]) -> UserInDB:
        # sub = await self.get_sub(token)
        user = await self.user_db.get_user_by_id(id=id)
        if not user:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, detail="Not register yet")
        return user
authenticator = Authenticator()

Another way is to implement this without class:
db = UserDatabase()


async def get_user_db():
    yield db

async def get_sub(token: Annotated[str, Depends(oauth2_scheme)]):
    #
    return sub

async def get_user(
    sub: Annotated[User, Depends(get_sub)],
    user_db: Annotated[UserDatabase, Depends(get_user_db)],
) -> UserInDB:
    user = await user.get_user_by_id(id=id)
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, detail="Not register yet")
    return user
    

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def index(user: Annotated[UserInDB, Depends(get_user)]):
    pass


if i doing so i will get the error response
cannot encode object: <coroutine object Authenticator.get_sub at 0x10b626890>, of type: <class 'coroutine'>

I think this error is caused by another part of your code. I tested the approach above and it works.

If you give me a minimal reproducible code example, I will try to help you out
